# Expression for this set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've got the set builder notation of a set:

`{x|x is an element of at most one of the three sets A, B, and C}`

And I must determine an expression for it using:

$\bigcup$, $\bigcap$, $-(substraction)$, $'(complement)$

What i have so far is:

$A \bigcap B' \bigcap C' \bigcup B \bigcap A' \bigcap C' \bigcup C \bigcap A' \bigcap B'$.

To me this reads as:

`x is either in A and NOT B and NOT C or B and NOT A and NOT C or C and NOT B and NOT A`

Which would be equivalent to:

$A - B - C \bigcup B - A - C \bigcup C - A - B$

Are my current paths correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's good but you are missing one case. "At most one" means...

Comment: Can you elaborate? What case am I missing?

Comment: Are you referring to the case where X is not in any set? So $(A' \bigcap B' \bigcap C')$?

Comment: At most one means possibly none!

Comment: Yes :) we posted simultaneously.

Comment: How would you express it using the $-(substitution)$? Just $A'-B'-C'$?

Comment: No, if you write $-B^\prime $ there are two negations (and not not in $ B $) so that is the same as $\cap B$.

Comment: $\bigcup A^\prime - B-C $ would work, or $ \bigcup X-A-B-C $ if you have a name for the total space.